# Scene design (color) changes after loading scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an FPS game using unity, but I've come across a problem. When I load my main scene after pressing "RESTART", it somehow causes my game to change appearance. But when I start the game from the main scene, it looks perfectly fine.. I've tried disabling Post Processing but I believe that's not what's causing the issue, I've provided some pictures of what happens when I load the main scene through the GameOver scene and when I load it through the MainScene.
[Scene loaded through the press of a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUaFc.jpg)  ------[Main Scene (what it's supposed to look like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCX7O.jpg)
Your help is much apreciated

Comment: Please improve your question by including a minimum working solution, so you can help us help you. For more information check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after quite a while of messing around with the settings I FINALLY figured it out. To get rid of uneven lighting between the scenes all you have to do is go to Window>Rendering>Lighting>Environment> (make sure "Auto Generate" is UNCHECKED) and click Generate lighting!!!